# Oracle DB: How to block drop table statement

Tags: oracle

I need to restrict access to DDL with some table in oracle, forbid drop of the table. How I can do this? I just can create DDL trigger for database and schema

```
create table my_table(
  id int primary key not null,
  first_val int,
  second_val int
);

create trigger delete_disabling_trigger
  before drop on database
begin
  if --some condition
    dbms_output.put_line('delete_disabling_trigger');
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-175,'Cant delete this table');
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need table that someone won't be able to drop you can create the table in another schema. Give grants to select, insert, update, delete and create synonym for user that is using the table.

Scenario: User X needs table T which can't be dropped.

```
Create user persist identified by password.
Create table persist.T ...
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on persist.T to X;
create synonym X.T for persist.T;
```

In such scenario X can manipulate data but can't change structure or drop table. Using trigger seems to be weird solution to block dropping table.

**EDIT**

```
create or replace trigger delete_disabling_trigger
  before drop on database
begin
    if(ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME = 'MY_TABLE') then --and ORA_DICT_OBJ_OWNER = 'YOUR_SCHEMA'  
    dbms_output.put_line('delete_disabling_trigger');
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Cant delete this table');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Yep, i know about this, thank you. But unfortunelly, i need to use trigger

Comment: @Evgeniy175 So it sounds as kind of homework. Generally triggers are something you would like to avoid in your real application.

Comment: Most of questions on StackOverflow about triggers are from homeworks as in real business application most developers will do as much as possible to avoid triggers.

Comment: @Evgeniy175 OK, I've edited answer and added trigger. That's really crazy thing. Good luck.

Comment: i hope that i use this once in my live ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have just implemented a trigger to stop the drop of 5 tables which are being dropped from 2 development schemas by some as yet unknown process.  We register the attempt in a table with an autonomous transaction, and stop the drop.

I hope to identify the process soon and get rid of the trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER whos_dropping_my_table
BEFORE DROP
ON database
declare
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
  insert into some_table_I_prepared_earlier
  VALUES( SUBSTR(ora_sysevent,1,50),
          SUBSTR(ora_dict_obj_owner,1,50),
          SUBSTR(ora_dict_obj_name,1,50),
          SUBSTR(ora_dict_obj_TYPE,1,50),
          UPPER(sys_context('USERENV','TERMINAL')),
          SYSDATE,
          UPPER(sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER'))
        );
  commit;

  if SUBSTR(ora_dict_obj_name,1,50) in     
           ('TABLE_1','TABLE_2','TABLE_3','TABLE_4','Table_5')
  then
    begin
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(num => -20998, 
                        msg => 'Stop deleting my table, whoever you are'); 
    end;
  end if;
end;
```